# how to configure cron job for magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I try to set the right cron for version 1.9.2.3
.
I've already put in Cpanel `*/5 * * * * website/cron.php` but I don't receive the order emails.

Can someone tell me, which lines to be modified in cron.php file?

Where to place the "crontab -e" or other additional codes ?

How can I verify which are the correct settings of cron according with my hosting server?

I have a shared SSH hosting, on Linux.

Comment: Your're trying to receive edit the cron for order emails on Magento?  Is this correct?  Or you are trying to get the cron to run every 5 minutes for overall cron.

Comment: Yes, i want to receive the order emails and also to make the cron to work properly. thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you are able to open crontab in your shared server then write that command
`crontab -e` to open editor. [it edit it via vim] .

To set your cron every 5 minutes you can use that command

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

After that press `Esc` and type `:wq` to save and quit your editor

This is good website to check cron times 
http://crontab.guru/#*/5_*_*_*_*

Comment: the :wq option assumes user chose vim to edit.  Other options are available, but still great answer.  Also, the ```crontab -e``` command is used on the terminal once you ssh into the server.

Comment: yes thanks for your opinion. you are right . Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but i don't know what to do with crontab-e.

Comment: I can not open the crontab, so please tell me if i can do some changes in the files cron.php and cron.sh from my public_html. thanks

Comment: Do you have sudo privileges?  I am unsure if this is required to use ```sudo``` in front.

Comment: thatnk you for answer, but i don't know where to look about 'sudo', in the front of cpanel i don't have this

Comment: You need to SSH into the server to be able to run crontab-e to view the crons set up

Answer (score 0):

`cron.sh` file indirectly calls `cron.php` file so for proper configuration you need to include `cron.sh` file in your server `crontab -e`

following command in your crontab

```
*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/Yourmagento/cron.sh
```

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem, after i found on youtube this idea, please comment if is alright, thanks:                                                                          https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NycpWVESqhA

Comment: If CRON job is not working properly, please follow below steps to send instant emails.

Copy Template.php file from 
app -> code -> core -> Mage -> Core -> Model -> Email
Create folder structure like 
app -> code -> local ->  Mage -> Core -> Model -> Email
Paste Template.php file in Email folder
Open Template.php file and go to line number 407 or search for the following code 
 if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {

Replace above code with following
 if (!($this->hasQueue()) && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {

Comment: If cron is not working properly, fix the cron. Do not edit core files.